# Rails 3 Wicked-pdf open pdf in new window from a form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I have a Rails 3 index view that contains a form because there are checkboxes to select rows and a submit button to create a pdf of those selected records using Wicked-pdf.

I would like the pdf to open in a new browser tab.  I included a `:target => "_blank"` in the submit, but it's not working.

This is the view:

```
<%= form_tag costprojects_viewprojects_path(format: "pdf") do %>
...
<td><%= check_box_tag "costproject_ids[]", costproject.id %></td>
...
<%= submit_tag "PDF Selected", :target => "_blank", :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
```

Controller action:

```
  def viewprojects
    @costprojects = Costproject.find(params[:costproject_ids])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render  :pdf => "costprojects.pdf",
                :show_as_html => params[:debug].present?,
                :page_size  => 'letter'
      end
    end
  end
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
<%= submit_tag "PDF Selected", :formtarget => "_blank", :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
```